# taking many random samples in parallel python

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I'm trying to repeatedly run a function that requires a few positional arguments and involves random number generation (to generate many samples of a distribution). For a MWE, I think this captures everything:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mup
from functools import partial

def rarr(xsize, ysize, k):
    return np.random.rand(xsize, ysize)
def clever_array(nsamp, xsize=100, ysize=100, ncores=None):
    np.random.seed()
    if ncores is None:
        p = mup.Pool()
    else:
        p = mup.Pool(ncores)
    out = p.map_async( partial(rarr, xsize, ysize), range(nsamp))
    p.close()
    return np.array(out.get())
```

Note that the final positional argument for rarr() is just a dummy variable, since I am using map_async(), which requires an iterable. Now if I run `%timeit clever_array(500, ncores = 1)` I get 208 ms, whereas `%timeit clever_array(500, ncores = 5)` takes 149 ms. So there is definitely some kind of parallelism happening (the speedup isn't terribly impressive for this MWE but is decent in my real code).

However, I'm wondering a few things -- is there a more natural implementation other than the dummy variable for `rarr()` passed as an iterable to `map_async` to run this many times? Is there any obvious way to pass the `xsize` and `ysize` args to `rarr()` other than `partial()`? And is there any way to ensure different results from the different cores other than initializing a different random.seed() every time?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically when we use multiprocessing we would expect different results from each invocation of a function, therefore it doesn't quite make sense to call the same function many times. In order to ensure the randomness of the sampling output, it is best to separate the random state (seed) from the function itself. The best approach as recommended by the [numpy official doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html#quick-start) is to use a `np.random.Generator` object, created via `np.random.default_rng([seed])`. With that we can modify your code to

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mup
from functools import partial

def rarr(xsize, ysize, rng):
    return rng.random((xsize, ysize))

def clever_array(nsamp, xsize=100, ysize=100, ncores=None):
    if ncores is None:
        p = mup.Pool()
    else:
        p = mup.Pool(ncores)
    out = p.map_async(partial(rarr, xsize, ysize), map(np.random.default_rng, range(nsamp)))
    p.close()
    return np.array(out.get())
```

Comment: I'm assuming that ```np.random.seed()``` should be removed as the first line of the definition of ```clever_array```? if so, this does indeed seem to solve a different problem which I didn't know I had :)

Comment: @user1451632 You are right, I've updated the solution! If you find it helpful please consider upvote and/or accept. Thanks :)

Comment: great, thanks -- also should point out that using a different map() function as the iterable is a good idea I hadn't previously considered